# Google GSI client not working with a blank screen

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, gmail, client

I used the script below and got a "Sign into google" button that just lead into an empty window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
      <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
      <script>
        function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
          console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
        }
        window.onload = function () {
          google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
            callback: handleCredentialResponse
          });
          google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
            { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
          );
          google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
        }
    </script>
    <div id="buttonDiv"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

This would usually lead into the classic sign into gmail but now it doesn't work suddenly. Last night it worked but now, I came back to my home and boom, doesn't work now. If anyone could fix this, it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full script, repo, or js fiddle so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I just did, can you take a look at it again? CSS file is default.

Comment: can you please verify that you have added your client id here YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you left out the client id on purpose for security reasons, but when I open the developer console it says to fix your client id.

Also you may have to enable the CORS policy locally to get it to work. You can run it on a webserver that enables this like XAMPP to enable it.

You can try to fix this by following this instruction on this documentation below:

```
Key Point: Add both http://localhost and http://localhost:<port_number> to the Authorized JavaScript origins box for local tests or development.
```

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid

[image]

Comment: I still get "The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID." with my client ID. Does that mean that my client ID is invalid?

Comment: @StarrySkies I updated the answer above to help you configure the origins locally, try that

Comment: This still does not work for me, if it is a problem with the code, can you fix it? If it is a problem with my client ID, is there another answer to what I am trying to create? I do not think I understand how to create one and my existing client ID does not work. Thank you.

Comment: Do I have to wait for my Client ID to be verified?

Comment: Potentially, I am not an expert with this, however if you are waiting for an ID to be verified, it might be unusable until then

Comment: Do you have some code that does not require an ID? I got an "Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid" even with verifying it.

Comment: Your project on Google developer console doesn't need to be verified until you are ready to release your application.   For s Gmail Scope it is a longer process which is going to require that you send in a video of your application running.   So fix your client id don't consern your self with verification yet